# Call EJB method by reflection have any Issues when code deploy on server?

Tags: reflection, orm, glassfish, ejb

I want to call an ejb method by reflection when i deploy my code to local glass-fish server it's work correctly. I want to know when load code main on server and have many call on that method, ejb architecture make some error?

```
@Stateless
public class AccessManager implements AccessManagerInt {

@EJB
public UserJpaControllerInt uj;
@EJB
public RoleJpaControllerInt rj;
@EJB
public ProductJpaControllerInt prj;
@EJB
public AppJpaControllerInt aj;






HashMap<String, Object> JPA_Mapper;

public Object doCreate(String JPA_Name, String methodName, String appCode, Integer userId, Class[] paramsType, Object[] params) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, AccassDeniedException {

    User u = uj.findUser(userId);
    Role r = rj.findRole(u.getId());
    String tableName = JPA_Name.split("JpaControllerInt")[0];

    if (haveAccess((String) TableTag.getInstance().get(tableName), (String) CRUD_Tag.getInstance().get("Create"), r) != -1) {
        try {
            Object obj = getJPA(JPA_Name);
            Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramsType);
            Product p = (Product) method.invoke(obj, params);
            return p;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AccessManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    throw new AccassDeniedException("YouHaveNoAccessToThisTable");
}

public Object doRead(String JPA_Name, String methodName, String appCode, String userId, Class[] paramsType, Object[] params) {

    return null;
}

public Integer haveAccess(String tableTag, String CRUD_Tag, Role role) {
    try {
        JSONObject access = new JSONObject(role.getAccess());
        JSONObject CRUD_Function = access.getJSONObject(CRUD_Tag);
        return CRUD_Function.getInt(tableTag);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccessManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return -1;
}

public Object getJPA(String JPA_Name) {
    if (JPA_Mapper == null) {
        JPA_Mapper = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : this.getClass().getFields()) {
            boolean flag = false;
            for (Annotation annotation : field.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation.toString().contains("javax.ejb.EJB")) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("Add JPA-> "+field.getType().getSimpleName());
                    JPA_Mapper.put(field.getType().getSimpleName(), field.get(this));
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AccessManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AccessManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return JPA_Mapper.get(JPA_Name);
}
```

}

Comment: Instances of session beans used by clients ( which coud be other session beans) are proxies whose instances are managed from the containner, so for example is totally unsafe to instantiate a bean with reflection or using the default constructor by the way.

Comment: I am not use reflection for instantiate ejb class. just use it for call method from that ejb class

Comment: I don't want to start to think of the problems which might occur, and in any case I do not understand why you would want to use reflection. But to test whether the idea works, take an EJB instance with CMT transactions and call a method which saves data to the db. If the db is indeed updated, I would then try to append code to the method end throwing a Runtime exception, and ensure that in this case there are no changes made to the db. This would make me confident that the method is transactional also when called via reflection, and would make me reasonably confident that the idea is ok.

Comment: Are you really calling an EJB method or do you call an Entity method?